# Как запустить одновременно два потока Python

Tags: python, многопоточность

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def func():
    print("h", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("e", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("o", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК

th1 = Thread(target=func)
th1.start()

print("h", end = "") #ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ В main thread
print("e", end = "") #ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ В main thread
print("l", end = "") #ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ В main thread
print("l", end = "") #ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ В main thread
print("o", end="")   #ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ В main thread

#ВЫВОД: hheelllolo
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#А КОГДА ЗАПУСКАЮ 2 ПОТОКА ВЫВОДИТ:

from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def func():
    print("h", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("e", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("o", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК

th1 = Thread(target=func)
th2 = Threa(target=func)

th1.start()
th2.start()

#ВЫВОД: hello
#       hello
#**КАК ЗАПУСТИТЬ ОДНОВРЕМЕННО ДВА ПОТОКА?**
```

Comment: цитата из почти первой ссылки в поиске на "потоки python" > Потоки позволяют запустить выполнение нескольких задач в конкурентном режиме в рамках одного процесса интерпретатора. При этом, нужно помнить о GIL. Советую почитать про потоки, конкурентность и Gil. Удачи :)

Answer (score 5):

Самый одновременный запуск выглядит так, но на выводе все равно будет `hellohello`

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep

ev = Event()

def func():
    ev.wait()
    print("h", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("e", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("o", end = "") #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК

th1 = Thread(target=func)
th2 = Thread(target=func)

th1.start()
th2.start()

ev.set()
```

Это происходит от того что машина быстрая и GIL не переключает потоки потому, что буферизованый print выполняется очень быстро.

Первый Ваш код также выводит hellohello на моей машине. Думаю просто hheelllolo то что вышло у вас это отголоски тормозов ОС, диска, запуска более тяжелой операции в фоне, антивируса, например, и подобного.

Треды в питоне используются только для блокирующих операций на диск или сеть, иногда чтоб подобрать медленный процесс. На быстрых операциях они бесполезны.
Работают они по очереди из-за того, что даже простые типы данных это объекты и они не присваиваются атомарно. Чтоб не блокировать интерпретатор при каждом присвоении и придумали GIL. Он дает каждому потоку определенное время на выполнение и перескакивает на другой.

Для операций на процессоре лучше использовать процессы. Там, конечно, возникает оверхед на обмен данными.

Comment: Если добавить в `print` параметр `flush=True`, то по крайней мере в `Google Colab` шанс перемешивания выводов повышается практически до 100%.

Answer (score 0):

я не думаю, что в контексте программирования что либо возможно прям одновременно. по сути любая асинхронность, многопоточной, многопроцессорность это задачи, на которые идет `overhead`, т.е задежрка на переключение между. вы можете сделать так:

```py
thread_pool = [тут ваши треды]

for thread in thread_pool:
    thread.start()
```

это будет почти одновременно.

Comment: это будет даже медленней чем у автора)

Comment: @eri зато правильнее)

Comment: ну нет, я по-другому запускаю)

Answer (score 0):

Если ещё и сбрасывать буфер печати с помощью параметра `flush=True`, то всё прекрасно перемешивается, по крайней мере в `Google Colab`. Спасибо eri за идею со стартовым флагом:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep

ev = Event()

def func():
    ev.wait()
    print("h", end = "", flush=True) #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("e", end = "", flush=True) #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "", flush=True) #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("l", end = "", flush=True) #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК
    print("o", end = "", flush=True) #ДОЧЕРНИЙ ПОТОК

for _ in range(20):

    th1 = Thread(target=func)
    th2 = Thread(target=func)

    ev.clear()

    th1.start()
    th2.start()

    ev.set()

    th1.join()
    th2.join()

    print(flush=True)
```

Вывод:

```
hehlloello
hheelllloo
hheelllloo
hhelellloo
hheelllolo
hheelllolo
hheelllolo
hhelellolo
hheelllloo
hehlleollo
hhelellolo
hehlleollo
hehlellolo
hheelllolo
hheelllloo
hehlellolo
hheelllloo
hheelllloo
hheelllloo
hheelllloo
```

Comment: на обычном ПЦ тоже.

Comment: синхронный вывод достаточно медленный, так что даже не обязательно синхронизировать старт эвентом.